# How to load or read all .plt files in R from directory into a single matrix

Tags: r

I'm trying to do some distance calculation based on the Geolife Trajecotry Dataset which is in .plt format. Currently I can read one .plt file at a time using code below.

```
trajectory = read.table("C:/Users/User/Desktop/20081023025304.plt", header = FALSE, quote = "\"", skip = 6, sep = ",")
```

My question is how I can read all the .plt files into R using a single command? I have try the command below but not work.

```
file_list <- list.files("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Geolife Trajectories 1.3/Data/000/Trajecotry")
```

The Geolife dataset path is :

```
Geolife Trajectories 1.3/Data/000/Trajectory/
```

Inside the Data folder there are total 82 folder starting 000 to 081

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very basic R. `list.files` is to list all the files in a specified directory. `read.table` is to read a specified file into R. You need to apply `read.table` to each file listed in the directory.

```
file_list <- list.files("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Geolife Trajectories 1.3/Data/000/Trajecotry", full=T)
file_con <- lapply(file_list, function(x){
    return(read.table(x, head=F, quote = "\"", skip = 6, sep = ","))
})

file_con_df <- do.call(rbind, file_con)
```